# Django JsonResponse with context

Tags: json, django, ajax

Can I use function JsonResponse and return .json file with dict context? I have only one .html and if I click in href ajax will get .json file and switch div's.

html:

```
<form id='FormSite' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div id='Bilboard'>
    <div id='Pic'>
    <video id='VideoStart' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" autoplay preload="true" loop >
        <source src="static/video/mainVideo.mp4"poster="static/img/facebook.png" type='video/mp4'>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
        <div id='Wpis'>
          <h1 id='HeaderWpis'>Aktualności:</h1>
          <div id='WpisChild'>
          {% for News in Messags %}
          <div id='NewsPapper'>
         <p style="font-size: 200% !important;">{{ News.title }}</p>
         <img src="static/img/line.png" style="width: 5%; height: 5%; position: relative !important; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"> 
         <p style="font-size: 150% !important;">{{ News.text |linebreaksbr }}</p>
         <img src="static/img/line.png" style="width: 5%; height: 5%; position: relative !important; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
         <p style="font-size: 150% !important;">{{ News.Data }}</p>
        </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def FirstStart(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    respone = {}
    UrlCut = request.GET.get('site','')
    if(len(UrlCut) > 0):
        File_read_to_div = open('templemates/'+UrlCut+'.txt','r')
    else:
        File_read_to_div = open('templemates/Main.txt','r')
    respone['Pic'] = str(File_read_to_div.readline())
    respone['h1'] = str(File_read_to_div.readline())
    respone['WpisChild'] = str(File_read_to_div.readline())
    #r
    Messages = NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data')
    context = {
        "Messags" : Messages
    }
    return JsonResponse(respone, context)
Messages = NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data')
context = {
    "Messags" : Messages
}
return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

ajax

```
 $.ajax({                                                                                                                           
    url: url,
    data: $('#FormSite').serialize(), 
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    success: function(response) {
        $($("#Pic").first()).replaceWith($(response['Pic']));
        $("#HeaderWpis").text(response['h1'])
        $($("#WpisChild").first()).replaceWith($(response['WpisChild']))
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('Bad connection');
    }

});
```

So, if I first load main.html  {{ News.title }} etc. work. But If ajax/django load this site from .txt he can't find context and display error function.

Answer (score 0):

JsonResponse doesn't take context as a parameter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

> The first parameter, data, should be a dict instance. If the safe parameter is set to False (see below) it can be any JSON-serializable object.

```
>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
b'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

In your case, you should be able to add messages to your dictionary:

```
respone['messages'] = NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data')

return JsonResponse(respone)
```

Comment: Im thinking and thinkg and I dont know how to include in my code :( I need add response = JsonResponse({'Messags: Messages}) ?

Comment: @MateuszBiałas I edited the answer to include a more specific example :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried it already :( Ajax return error function.

Comment: You may need to get your messages as a dict also, using values: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values 

NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data').values()

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. With values() I already tried. Maybe I will create function in py which will be create code html and send as string in dict. I dont have any other idea.

Comment: But still I don't know why it's not work. Maybe python can't download this data from base?